# VueJs app building Killed in Docker - Heap limit allocation fail

Tags: docker, vue.js, out-of-memory

I have run the docker vuejs frontend application but it doesn't build App. It gives following errors.
Also tried following solutions.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
ca[44:0x560fe6c19b40]   174036 ms: Mark-sweep 995.0 (1006.6) -> 992.7 (1006.6) MB, 769.9 / 0.1 ms  (+ 285.8 ms in 42 steps since start of marking, biggest step 18.2 ms, walltime since start of marking 1439 ms) (average mu = 0.268, current mu = 0.271) alloca[44:0x560fe6c19b40]   175415 ms: Mark-sweep 995.1 (1006.6) -> 993.7 (1007.3) MB, 1277.0 / 0.1 ms  (+ 44.0 ms in 7 steps since start of marking, biggest step 24.5 ms, walltime since start of marking 1370 ms) (average mu = 0.156, current mu = 0.042) allocat

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x560fe2b49999]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x560fe2af50f0]
Security context: 0x299ca5580921 <JSObject>
    2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x1db008252291] [/app/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/applySourceMap.js:~58] [pc=0x2ade2334e5ae](this=0x1908b25004b9 <undefined>,0x142d6bdf8629 <String[9]: function >,0x26c3bdf55161 <Object map = 0x3f9aac4f1771>)
    3: walk(aka SourceNode_walk) [0x42e5136b1f1] [/app/node_mod...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Aborted
```

I did following :

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

Still not working
Again tried with following:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build --mode development
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to build your VueApp without Docker? Maybe your docker instance is out of memory?

If you open Docker Desktop and go to `Settings > Resources` you can increase the CPU's and memory usage.

Comment: I am running it through virtual machine

Comment: Hmm maybe the virtual machine is running out of memory then? Perhaps you can allocate more memory in there.

Comment: Thanks, solved it on my side, had to increase swap memory

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a file in operating system called .wslconfig

[wsl2]
memory=3GB

Probably when giving the command docker build -t ... the limited memory limit in .wslconfig is exceeded.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).